# Find elements that are not present in a Set a return a new Set containing these missing elements

Tags: java, collections, set, java-stream

I have an enum `Tags` containing a complete list of tags which can be applied to instances of the `Product` class. In this class there is an instance variable `tags` which is a `Set` of `Strings` that contains a subset of these tags. What I'm trying to do is find a set of tags that has yet been applied to a certain product and return it as a new `Set` using a method.

```java
        Set<String> suggestedTags = new HashSet<>();
        Arrays.stream(Tags.values())
                .forEach(tagsList -> {
                    if (!this.tags.contains(tagsList.getTagName())) {
                        suggestedTags.add(tagsList.getTagName());
                    }
                });
        return suggestedTags;
```

I have tested the above code and it works as expected. However, I wish to accomplish the same result in just one statement. Something like this:

```java
        return Arrays.stream(Tags.values())
                .map(tagsList -> {
                    // code to find missing elements goes here
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I'm stuck here as I'm not sure which intermediate operation would be suitable for such a task. I thought of using `map()` and `filter()` but no luck so far.

The enum `Tags` is as follows:

```java
    public enum Tags {

        BIRTHDAY("birthday"),
        GRADUATION("graduation"),
        GET_WELL_SOON("get well soon");

        final String tagName;

        private Tags(String tagName) {
            this.tagName = tagName;
        }

        public String getTagName() {
            return tagName;
        }
    }
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```java
Set<String> suggestedTags = Arrays.stream(Tags.values())
                                  .map(Tags::getTagName)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
suggestedTags.removeAll(tags);
```

but that's still two expressions. Still a lot cleaner than your first version, though.

If you switch from sets of `String`s to [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html)s of `Tags`, though...

```java
EnumSet<Tags> suggestedTags = EnumSet.complementOf(tags);
// Assuming EnumSet<Tags> tags = EnumSet.of(Tags.BIRTHDAY);
// suggestedTags contains GRADUATION and GET_WELL_SOON
```

This also has the nice side effects of making the sets a lot faster and taking up less memory.

Comment: wasn't aware of EnumSet until now. Thanks for the info, I'll try using it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to filter the `Tags` which is not in `Product`, and get name of `Tags` the below code should work

```
  return Arrays.stream(Tags.values()).filter(tag -> !this.tags.contains(tag)).map(Tags::getTagName).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Intellij is giving me a warning saying that the order of filter and map should be switched, will the order cause any notable issues?

Comment: @CMK when your set contains tag names, it’s just simpler to map to names first, i.e. `.map(Tags::getTagName) .filter(name -> !tags.contains(name))` because you’re not invoking `getTagName()` twice per element then.